# How to exclude calling class in JGroups RpcDispatcher calls

Tags: java, cluster-computing, distributed-computing, rpc, jgroups

I want a single class to invoke the same method in multiple other classes, without trying to do so on itself.

For example, *RpcDispatcher* calling `rsp_list = disp.callRemoteMethods(null, "print", new Object[]{10}, new Class[]{int.class}, opts);` should not try and invoke `print` on itself, only the other channel members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an exclusion list in `RequestOptions` passed to the call, or use `TransientFlag.DONT_LOOPBACK` (preferred, as more efficient). The transient flag is also set in `RequestOptions`.